# How To Control Input Type Dropdown Menu With Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a web site. In this web site I have created a form. So , there are 2 dropdown menus like below.

I want to limit the number of adults and children to 9. One can select i.e. 4 adults and 0 to 5 children, or 6 adults and 0-3 children, but never more than 9 in total.

The code I tried out so far only worked for Adults , not for the Total ( Adults + Children ). But , it's not compulsory to select a value to the children menu. If th user wants, he can keep it as 0.

How can I do this ??

Here is the Jquery part I tried out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {

      var adults = parseFloat($('#adults').val());
      var children = parseFloat($('#children').val());
      var infants = $('#infants').val();
      var Total = adults + children;

      $('#adults').change(function() {
          if (this.value > 8) {// check against the value of the adults drop down
              $("#children").prop('disabled', true);
          } else {
              $("#children").prop('disabled', false);  // probably need to re-enable it
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Here are HTML Dropdown view.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="signupForm">

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature">
    <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
    Adults :
    <select name="adults" class="form-control" id="adults">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
    </select> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature">
    <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
    Children :
    <select name="children" class="form-control" id="children">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
    </select> <br>

  </div>

  <a href="#" id="ghsubmitbtn" class="btn btn-success">Search Flight Data</a>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below snippet might help you.

```
   var totalAdultChild = 9;
   $('#adults').change(function() {
       var adultValue = this.value;
       if (this.value > 8) {                     
           $("#children").prop('disabled', true);
       } else {
           $("#children").prop('disabled', false);  
           $('#children option').each(function(index,element){
               if((totalAdultChild-adultValue)<this.value){
                   $(this).hide();
               } else {
                   $(this).show();
               }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: When I try this , when I select 5 , it gives 4 to the child. But , that's not compulsory. If user wants only , he can select from children menu. How can I do it ??

Comment: It's Worked !! Thank U !! :D

Comment: I need your help again - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51028333/how-to-control-input-type-dropdown-select-options-menu-with-jquery